# Unknown provider when try to call my authorise service

Tags: angularjs, web, authorization, router

In my angular 1.5 app i try to call an authorisation service in order to predict the group of the current user.

I read the way to do so before the app is loaded is by adding to the routerProvider.

However i see it's not possible as the service wasn't initialised by then:

```
  app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$compileProvider', 'authorizationService',
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $compileProvider, authorizationService) {

            $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

            $stateProvider.state('home', {
                url: '/',
                template: '<home-component></home-component>',
                component: 'homeComponent',
                params: {
                    selectedFilter: undefined
                },
                resolve: {
                    ldapGroup: function (authorizationService) {
                        return authorizationService.getLdapGroup().then(
                            function successCallback(data) {
                                $scope.isAdOps = data;
                            },
                            function errorCallback(response) {
                                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                                // or server returns response with an error status.
                                console.log(response);
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            })
```

I get:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: authorizationService
```

Comment: you don't need to inject `authorizationService` into config, only into resolve function

Comment: thanks. it worked. how should i save the result globally or pass it to each component? as `$scope is not defined`

Comment: instead of `$scope.isAdOps = data;` you need `return data;`, then in your controller (where you use `isAdOps`) simply **inject** your resolved variable `ldapGroup`. I believe this will return an actual value from an asynchronous callback (_so no need to resolve a promise with_ `.then`), just assign it with `$scope.isAdOps = ldapGroup;`

Comment: I'm using components and not controllers.
`so no need to resolve a promise with .then` so i assign promise into ldapGroup? wouldn't it make the call to the AuthorizationService async?

Comment: components have controllers as far as I know. Whateven `getLdapGroup` uses (i'm assuming `$http`), it already returns a promise, which is an asynchronous callback. But because you **resolve** it, it turns it into a synchronous callback that simply returns your data. One way or another you need to assign it in the controller's controller with `$scope.isAdOps = ldapGroup;` by first injecting `ldapGroup`

Comment: sorry to ask, how do i inject? like any other service/dependency or via state variable?

`(function (app) {
    app.component('searchBarComponent', {

        templateUrl: 'partials/search-bar.html',
        bindings: {isFullList: '='},
        controller: ['$http', '$state', '$stateParams', '$scope', 'updateService', 'ldapGroup',
            function ($http, $state, $stateParams, $scope, updateService, ldapGroup) {

                console.log("in search bar component");
                var self = this;`

Comment: yeah, you got it, so I guess you just need `self.isAdOps = ldapGroup;` in the component's controller

Comment: when i do `(function (app) {
  ..
        controller: ['$http', '$state', '$stateParams', '$scope', 'searchService',
            'countriesService', 'languagesService', 'flagsService', 'filtersCriteriaService',
            'topBarService', 'updateService', 'ldapGroup',
            function ($http, $state, $stateParams, $scope, searchService, countriesService,
                      languagesService, flagsService, filtersCriteriaService, topBarService, updateService, ldapGroup) {`

i get an error: `angular.js:14800 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ldapGroupProvider <- ldapGroup`